# remove or fill 'NULL' in weka for data mining

Tags: weka, data-mining

i am using weka tool for data preprocessing ,one of my attribute named (price) is filled with a value called 'NULL' how to remove or replace this null with the average value of that class.Here i have already tried **unsupervised.attribute.ReplaceMissing** values but there is no change